# Modify component output using module......Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, custom-component, joomla3.0

I am a new developer in joomla.
I just want to integrate joomla component to custom module.When a user install module then output of related component must be change as per module file  automatically .
I want to use filters with Jreviews_geomap_addon.So create a module to use filter icons into geomap...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module should have a form or link that submits or changes the URL when clicking on the links. You can then read the url parameters using:

```
$var_name = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('var_name');
```

You can then use the $var_name to change what data is displayed by your component.

Comment: Thanks, for reply but i need ajax filtering for location in jreviews_geomap_addon component using custom module.               And i don't want to do any changes in component file.just to override file of component  using module with their functions.